# How to restore data after repartitioning a drive?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, data-recovery

Yesterday night I properly shut down my laptop, but the next morning when I opened my laptop, I found that two of the drives were missing.

I checked Disk Management and it said that there was "90GB of free un-allocated space available". I created a partition in the available free space and consequently lost all my data.

After that I tried to recover my lost data, but was only able to recover 10%. After 2-3 hours, I saw that the the partition that I created earlier was missing again. I also checked Disk Management and saw the same thing as earlier.

Now I am wondering whether there is a hard disk problem or OS issue. I am using Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit and my laptop is a Lenovo ThinkPad R61. How can I fix this problem and prevent it from occurring in the future?

Comment: This is not a security issue, so it's off topic. Flagged to migrate to SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing problem with your hardware then you can generate window 7 System diagnostic Report. For how to perform Window 7 system diagnostics you can read  [Windows 7 System Diagnostic Report.](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/troubleshoot-instantly-with-the-windows-7-system-diagnostic-report/4313). Second option is to go for IDE Drive Diagnostics to perform basic test for hard drive health for your case you perform [Lenovo Hard Drive Quick Test](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-70578).

Comment: @Ali, I have checked with Windows 7 System Diagnostic program and also checked my Hard disk from BIOS. I don't find any error from these tests. I am unable to use Lenovo Hard Drive Quick Test software because my system will not support it. Please help me.

Comment: Can anyone let me know the exact problem in my case? I am facing this problem repeatedly. Waiting for an answer soon. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I am facing same problem with my laptop from last 1 month. Please help me what to do... Waiting for your response at the earliest. Thanks in advance...